# Add c++ support in a autotools project?

Tags: c++, c, autotools, automake

I am now writing  an app that need using c++ in my c code.My problem is i can't compile through the c++ code.

i have two source folders,cpp (contains only a c source file ) and src (contains only a c++ source file ).

my configure.in is just like this,very simple

```
AC_PREREQ([2.68])
AC_INIT([tste], [1.0], [ee@b.com])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE()
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile cpp/Makefile src/Makefile] )
AC_OUTPUT
```

./Makefile.am:

```
SUBDIRS= src cpp
```

./cpp/Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS=main
main_SOURCES=main.c
```

./src/Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS=test
test_SOURCES=testcpp.cpp
```

When i using make to compile my project , the error occurs:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hujin/Desktop/test/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hujin/Desktop/test/src'
Making all in cpp
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hujin/Desktop/test/cpp'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `main.o', needed by `main'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hujin/Desktop/test/cpp'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: I think you may have transcribed something wrong - src contains a cpp file, and cpp only contains a .c file. Perhaps you could check in your test project onto github (or similar), so people could look at it and try it out more easily?

Comment: Think you, i really got something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your skin, I wouldn't have split the project in submakefiles since it all goes to a single target ("tste").

You better put all of your source files in the root `Makefile.am` (you can generate more than one output from it):

```
# ./Makefile.am:

bin_PROGRAMS=main test

main_SOURCES=cpp/main.c
test_SOURCES=src/testcpp.cpp
```

Change your `configure.ac`to something like:

```
# configure.ac
AC_PREREQ([2.68])

AC_INIT([tste], [1.0], [ee@b.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/testcpp.cpp])

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Then run:
    aclocal && autoconf && automake
    ./configure
    make

Here are some good links:

- [A tutorial for porting to autoconf & automake](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/)
- [Using Automake and Autoconf with C++](http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake)
- [autotut: Using GNU auto{conf,make,header}](http://seul.org/docs/autotut/)

Comment: Sounds like you follow http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RecursiveMakeConsideredHarmful ?  The structure of autotools projects is commonly recursive, though.

Comment: It is to be recursive when it has reasons to that. It is not even "forbiden" nor "a must" to recurse. I see no reason for such complication in this example. Maybe @bixuehujin simplified the problem to make the question, though.